# 365 Powershell Load User Info

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm new to `Exchange 365` and `Powershell`.  I have user information that I want to add and am trying to use the Powershell code below.  However, it errors out on me.  Thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
$input=Import-Csv D:\Users.csv
foreach($line in $input)
{
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $line.UserPrincipalName -Title $line.Title -City $line.City -Country $line.Country -Department $line.Department -Fax $line.Fax -MobilePhone $line.MobilePhone -Office $line.Office -PhoneNumber $line.PhoneNumber -PostalCode $line.PostalCode -State $line.State -StreetAddress $line.StreetAddress
}
```

The error I get is attached says: `method invocation failed because system object doesn't contain a method Foreach`.

Comment: I don't know why you are getting that error but you input file is very well formed so are you able to get away with this?

`Import-Csv D:\Users.csv | ForEach-Object{Set-MsolUser @_}` If it helps I will explain. Wonder if your powershell session is not aware of the `foreach` construct you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try pipelining the CSV directly like Matt's suggestion:

```
Import-Csv D:\Users.csv | ForEach-Object{Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -Title $_.Title -City $_.City -Country $_.Country -Department $_.Department -Fax $_.Fax -MobilePhone $_.MobilePhone -Office $_.Office -PhoneNumber $_.PhoneNumber -PostalCode $_.PostalCode -State $_.State -StreetAddress $_.StreetAddress}
```